# class-validator case-insensitive enum validation?

Tags: node.js, enums, case-sensitive, class-validator

I have anum like this:

```
export enum UserRole {
  USER,
  ADMIN,
  BLOGGER
}
```

and create.user.dto like this

```
import { IsEmail, IsEnum, IsNotEmpty, IsOptional } from 'class-validator';
import { UserRole } from './user.entity';

export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  firstName: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  lastName: string;

  @IsOptional()
  username: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsEnum(UserRole)
  role: UserRole;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  password: string;
}
```

Now role validation does not fail if I only post the role uppercase('ADMIN','USER') or 'BLOGGER'.

How to make class-validator not case sensitive? I mean, validate true also for 'admin' 'aDmIn'.

Comment: ENUM will not do this, and i dont think that @IsIn(Array) is case-insensitive, you have to write custom validator, where you can use this condition  `array.includes(incoming-value.toLowercase)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

then you need a regexp validation via `@Matches`.

```js
  @IsOptional()
  @Matches(`^${Object.values(UserRole).filter(v => typeof v !== "number").join('|')}$`, 'i')
  role: UserRole;
```

the final rule is `/^USER|ADMIN|BLOGGER$/i`, where `i` ignores the case.

Answer (score 9):

For what it's worth, you could also use [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#class-validator)'s `@Transform` decorator to match your enum casing.

```
export enum UserRole {
 USER = "user",
 ADMIN = "admin",
 BLOGGER = "blogger"
}
```

Then in your DTO:

```
@IsOptional()
@Transform(({ value }) => ("" + value).toLowerCase())
@IsEnum(UserRole)
role: UserRole;
```

Worked for me with `"class-validator": "^0.14.0"`

Answer (score 2):

your enum should like this

```
export enum UserRole {
  USER = "USER",
  ADMIN = "ADMIN",
  BLOGGER = "BLOGGER"
}
```

is proven works in case-insensitive or vice versa